# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified axis.

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified axis. 
$x=3y^2$, $y=1$ and $x=0$ around the y-axis.

Comment: It is $\frac  {9 \pi} {5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture. The curve $x=3y^2$ is a rightward opening parabola with axis of symmetry the $x$-axis. We use cross-sections of the solid perpendicular to the $y$-axis.

The cross-sections are disks ("circles") of radius $x$. Thus the volume is
$$\int_{y=0}^1 \pi x^2\,dy.$$
To evaluate, use the fact that $x=3y^2$.